# Remove all Heading zeroes except if it is the zero before "," or "." or zeroes after "," or "."

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input string that will be validated by 2 regexes.

```
        var pattern = /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;   
        var pattern2 = /^[0-9]+(,[0-9]{0,2})?$/;

        txtAmount.SetText(txtAmount.GetText().trim().replace(/^0+/, '')); 
        if (pattern.test(txtAmount.GetText()) == false && pattern2.test(txtAmount.GetText()) == false)
    //Dont pass test

else 
 //pass
```

The problem is i need to somehow Trim the Leading zeroes of the string but not the zero before "." or "," or anny zeroes after the "." or ","

As it is now 0.2  or 0,3 -->  .2   ,3

Anny ideas?

Comment: Example desired input and output? What should happen to for example: `000.000`, `000 00.00`, etc?

Comment: 00,02 -->  0,02   
00.02 --> 0.02
010,20 --> 10,20
010.20 --> 10.20 

Got An answer that fulfilled this tho, thanks for input annyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
.replace(/^0+(?![.,])/,'')
```

Example:

```
"0000.2".replace(/^0+(?![.,])/,'')
>>> "0.2"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, woorked as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

try `/^0+(?!\.)/`

results:

```
0000.2   0.2
0.2      0.2
0.00002  0.00002
```